# Combining nested collection in mongodb with documents written from parallel nodes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm in the process of figuring out whether I can use MongoDB to help with our storage and processing issues. The idea is that computation will be done on each node in a multi-processed way and written to mongodb with a unique mongodb **ObjectId**. The data structure is as follows below from a dictionary:

```
{a: {b: {c: [100, 200, 300]} }
```

a, b and c are integer keys

When the computation has been done and all the records written out to mongo, the documents must be combined such that the we group by the top level a, then by b and then c. So two documents might contain (**Example A**):

document1: `{24: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}}`

document2: `{24: {68: {12: [100, 200]}}}`

*then if we combine:*

combined: `{24: {67: {12: [100, 200]}, 68: [100, 200]}}`

and if we had another couple of documents (**ExampleB**):

document1: `{24: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}}`

document2: `{24: {67: {12: [300, 400]}}}`

combined: `{24: {67: {12: [100, 200, 300, 400]}}}`

What is the best approach to combine these nested structures. I could loop through each document by hand and do this say in python, but is there are smarter approach to this? I need to keep the underlying data structure.

Comment: Does the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) directive in mongodb not solve this for you?

Comment: Why not use map reduce? The dynamic keys make it a bit tougher to aggregate the result.

Comment: @AlexLaties, I would want to do these $push as a batch job and because of the data structure, wonder if its too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is not smart in doing the aggregation with python? Consider the following function:

```
def aggregate(documents, base_document=None, unique=True):
    # use unique=False to keep all values in the lists, even if repeated
    # like [100, 100, 200, 300], leave it True otherwise
    for doc in documents:
        if isinstance(doc, list):
            if base_document is None: base_document = []
            for d in doc:
                base_document.append(d)
            if unique==True: base_document = set(base_document)
            base_document = sorted(base_document)
        else:
            if base_document is None: base_document = {}
            for d in doc:
                b = base_document[d] if d in base_document \
                    else [] if isinstance(doc[d], list) else {}
                base_document[d] = aggregate([doc[d]], base_document=b)
    return base_document
```

Tested with the following set of documents, it produces the aggregation :

```
documents = [   {20: {55: { 7: [100, 200]}}},
                {20: {68: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {20: {68: {12: [500, 200]}}},
                {23: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {23: {68: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {24: {67: {12: [300, 400]}}},
                {24: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {24: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {24: {67: {12: [300, 500]}}},
                {24: {67: {13: [600, 400]}}},
                {24: {67: {13: [700, 900]}}},
                {24: {68: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {25: {67: {12: [100, 200]}}},
                {25: {67: {12: [300, 400]}}},   ]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(aggregate(documents))

''' 
{20: {55: {7: [100, 200]}, 68: {12: [100, 200, 500]}},
 23: {67: {12: [100, 200]}, 68: {12: [100, 200]}},
 24: {67: {12: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], 13: [400, 600, 700, 900]},
      68: {12: [100, 200]}},
 25: {67: {12: [100, 200, 300, 400]}}}
'''
```

Comment: Almost there, but there will still need to be a number of documents that are keyed on the first id, so it looks like {24: {..}, 20:{..}}

Comment: @Navonod I don't understand your point in your comment, Can you explain it to me, maybe point what is wrong with the answer obtained. I edited the answer, to whow the resulting dictionary more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @chapelo:

```
##Import python mongodb API:
import pymongo

##Build aggregation framework:
def aggregate(documents, base_document=None, unique=True):
    # use unique=False to keep all values in the lists, even if repeated
    # like [100, 100, 200, 300], leave it True otherwise
    for doc in documents:
        if isinstance(doc, list):
            if base_document is None: base_document = []
            for d in doc:
                base_document.append(d)
            if unique==True: base_document = set(base_document)
            base_document = sorted(base_document)
        else:
            if base_document is None: base_document = {}
            for d in doc:
                b = base_document[d] if d in base_document \
                    else [] if isinstance(doc[d], list) else {}
                base_document[d] = aggregate([doc[d]], base_document=b)
    return base_document

##Open mongodb connection:
db = pymongo.MongoClient()

##Query old documents without ObjectIds:
old_dict = db.old.collection.find({},{"_id":0})

##Run old documents through aggregation framework:
new_dict =  aggregate(old_dict)

##Insert aggregated documents into new mongodb collection:
for i in new_dict:
   db.new.collection.insert({i:new_dict[i]})

##Close mongodb connection:
db.close()
```